# Capistrano deploy from Git HTTP repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, http, deployment, capistrano

Has anyone experience with Capistrano deployment from a Git repository over HTTP?

The following *deploy.rb* is not working:

```
set :repository,  'http://git.repository-domain.com:4442/git/repo.git'
set :scm_username, "git_username"
set :scm_password, "git_password"
set :scm, :git
```

It is working if you pass a repository in as following though:

```
set :repository,  'http://git_username:git_password@git.repository-domain.com:4442/git/repo.git'
```

The latter only works as long as either the username or password have no special chars. URL-encoding those chars will result in a failure.

**UPDATE**: a more precise description of the problem is available in the ticket at https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/384

Comment: Why why why! This upsets me so much! ;)

Comment: You mean the repo on HTTP?

Comment: The http bit. Why can't you use https?

Comment: Good point. Lack of HTTPS is temporary. But do you think it would resolve the problem?

Comment: It might. I've never deployed with cap over https though. Had no problems installing gems though with it. I wonder if you could try without the scm_username and password and or changing to https

Comment: I'll try with HTTPS once configured, I've had no problems with SVN on HTTPS.

Comment: Are you allowed to talk about SVN? I'm sure that's banned language in the realms of Git :) Good luck, I hope you get it fixed.

Comment: If you use VPN server, i have solution how to deploy through ssh protocol. If you need it I can answer.

Comment: Thanks for the offer itsnikolay, VPN is fortunately out.

Comment: HTTPS didn't help anyhow as expected. It's not making any use of `:scm_username` and `:scm_password`, but at least, fortunately, prompts for them as it goes through the deployment.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Capistrano Git HTTPS authentication will be resolved in Capistrano 3 where you can set repository and its credentials with:

```
set :repo_url, 'https://git.repository-domain.com:4442/git/repo.git'
set :git_http_username, 'username'
set :git_http_password, 'password'
```

Also, what already works in Capistrano 3, is the username:password in the repository URL even if the password includes special characters:

```
set :repo_url, 'https://ain:3490jL?a@git.repository-domain.com:4442/git/repo.git'
```

For more up-to-date info see https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano

Comment: It's git_http_username and git_http_password, without the "s" according to https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/search?q=git_http_username&unscoped_q=git_http_username